# How to show an indication if an element exceeds the size of its parent using CSS?

Tags: html, css

Say I've got a div `.parent` which contains another div `.child`. Can I, and if so, how do I show an indication (i.e. an icon) when `.child` exceeds the width of `.parent`, using CSS?

I've accomplished my goal using jQuery (see below example), but I'm looking for a CSS only solution, as I'm trying to keep my jQuery usage as low as possible.

Note: the `.child` div has a dynamic width.

Another note: I prefer not to edit the content of the divs

```js
var x = $('.child').offset().left + $('.child').width();

var y = $('.parent').offset().left + $('.parent').width();

if (x > y) {

  var z = x - y;

  $('.child')
    .append($('<div></div>')
      .css('left', z - 10)
      .css('position', 'absolute')
      .css('top', $('.child').height() / 2 - 10)
      .text('>'));

}
```

```css
.parent {
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.child {
  position: absolute;
  top: 40px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 100px;
  width: 400px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    Some text
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You're looking to display an indication *other* than a scrollbar, presumably.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Yes I am. However this indication doesn't need an action or anything (it doesn't need to scroll)

Comment: I've removed the [tag:jquery] tag, since you're not looking for a jQuery solution.

Comment: CSS cannot do this, the one thing kind of alike is text-overflow:ellipsis, you do need javascript (or a js framework)

Comment: As far as  i know , you can never check a condition (which is needed here ) using css alone. You will need js for this.

Comment: @SoorajChandran: Well, there are some limited checks built into CSS, such as `:checked` for checkboxes which you can use for styling things next to them. I've been quietly hoping that someone will post an answer along the lines of "You're looking for this little-known pseudo-class :x-y-z!" :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder May be i used the wrong word. What  i meant was a comparison operation ( here we need to compare the offset with of parent and child ) is not possible using CSS alone. Even i was looking in the comments , for some answer using `calc` and some pseudo elements.

Comment: Hi I looked for a solution with a friend of mine, which is a really crack in css/css3 and so on...I expected it, but there is really no way to do this only with css...you will need js for this - but good question sir! Cheers.

Comment: Where the width of the child div comes from if it's not decided by the content?

Comment: Aside from the scrollbar, I suppose you could cause certain effects with `text-overflow` on the child.

Comment: @Pangloss The width is determined by another library.

Comment: Something like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/5z3mpkw4/) (change .child's width to 100 to see the little square "disappear") would only work if certain stars aligned, i.e. icon same color as .parent bgcolor, icon position could change based on .child width, being able to hack that setting of .parent::after's bgcolor to match its parent's bgcolor).

Answer (score 0):

I read your question and comments. And i  had an idea.
Yes i think best way for your problem is use javascript.

But I decided to find alternatives :)

That's why i spent 10 minutes of time on this solution.

Yes it's work only for  webkit browsers. But it's possible.

```css
.parent {
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  overflow:auto;
}

.child {
  position: absolute;
  top: 40px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 100px;
  width: 400px;
}

.parent1 {
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  overflow:auto;
}

.child1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 40px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 400px;
  width: 100px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar {
      background: transparent;
}


::-webkit-scrollbar-button:horizontal:end  {
    border-top: 8px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 8px solid transparent;
    border-right: 8px solid transparent;
    border-left:8px solid red; 
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-button:vertical:end  {
    border-left: 8px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 8px solid transparent;
    border-right: 8px solid transparent;
    border-top:8px solid blue; 
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    Some text
  </div>
</div>

<div class="parent1">
  <div class="child1">
    Some text
  </div>
</div>
```